# I need to clarify with this simple but quite interesting probability problem

Tags: probability

There is this question, I could understand it and I could do it. I would just like to clarify a bit further.

A class consists of seven boys and nine girls. Two different members of the class are chosen at random. $A$ is the event {the first person is a girl}, and $B$ is the event {the second person is a girl}. Find the probabilities of $B$.

The way I did it: $P(B)=P(A\cap B)+P(A'\cap B)=\frac{9}{16}\times\frac{8}{15}+\frac{7}{16}\times\frac{9}{15}=\frac{9}{16}$.

My question is can we just do $P(B)=\frac{9}{16}$ right away? What does it say about the event? If we try to find P(A), we get $\frac{9}{16}$ as well. Does it say that it does not matter whether we pick the girl first or second? It is surprising to see this. Does it always work, or is it a coincidence?

Any additional comments/insights about this problem are very much welcome.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a coincidence.  Since you didn't condition on the result of the first pick, you can pick the two members, then reverse the order.  The chance the second in this experiment is a girl is the same as the chance the first in the original experiment is a girl.